# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge USB MTP protocol not working

Tags: samsung, usb, mtp

I'm trying to root my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, but I can't get the USB to work with MTP.

- I've enabled USB debugging and set the USB mode to MTP, but still won't be recognized by the computer.
- I've tried installing new USB device drivers from https://developer.samsung.com and it still didn't work.
- I've factory reset the device, still to no avail.
- I've also tried multiple Micro USB cables, which all have the USB Trident Trademark. None of them get recognized by my computer, and neither do they get recognized as plugged in on my laptop when I run `lsusbn`.
- I've also tried getting plugging in my Samsung Galaxy S3, which I believe didn't get recognized either.

When I plug the phone into the computer, I expect to see the prompt or the notification asking to allow the computer to access the phone's data, but it never happens.

Does anybody know what could be the issue here?

Comment: Based on all of these, perhaps the USB cables are charging-only cables, not data cables. Have you tried it with other non-Android peripheral that needs to transfer data, like an external SSD/HDD/BD/DVD/CD/SD card player?

Comment: What about `adb`?  Enable it and try to connect to it (`adb devices` and `adb shell`). If this also does not work I would try to boot the PC using  Live-Linux DVD and see if MTP works in this configuration. If it works it is a PC/Linux problem.

Comment: samsung microUSB differ from other usb cables. on linux no drivers required. what is `lsusbn`?